# Opencart - Can I import live data into localhost database

Tags: php, perl, opencart

I constructed opencart shop on my localhost, then trying to import data from live site into it. I exported live database into SQL file and then importing into local host. In both instances, I am using phpmyadmin. However, I am facing these problems

- I get a file too large error (limit is 4MB) but importing only 950KB file
- Can I import data on top of opencart database?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting this error when you try to import the sql file into your database using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Perhaps posting your code would help...

Comment: yes..

`You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit`

Comment: Did you try opencart's in built backup tool ?